# Why does pthread_join crash (seg fault) at 306 Joins?

Tags: multithreading, segmentation-fault, pthreads, pthread-join

I'm playing around with creating a BUNCH of threads, just see learn a bit more about pthread.  I've copied a program I found, and instead of making 1 thread, and joining it, it will create X threads, and join them.

When I tried 100 threads (MAX_THREAD 100), it worked fine.  So I tried 1000 threads, and it crashed.  Then 500 threads, and it crashed.  Loading it into GDB showed it crashed at 306 threads.  However, it's inconsistent.  I can set it to 304 on the system I'm using, and sometimes it'll crash, sometimes it wont.

I'm keeping all the pthread_t's from the pthread_create in an array, so I shouldn't be trying to join the same thread twice.

The segfault happens here:
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x004e420e in pthread_join () from /lib/libpthread.so.0

Here's the code I'm using.

Code:

```
#define MAX_THREAD 306

#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int something_worked(void) {
    /* thread operation might fail, so here's a silly example */
    void *p = malloc(10);
    free(p);
    return p ? 1 : 0;
}

void *myThread(void *result)
{
   if (something_worked()) {
       *((int*)result) = 42;
       pthread_exit(result);
   } else {
       pthread_exit(0);
   }
}

int main()
{
   pthread_t tid[MAX_THREAD];
   void *status[MAX_THREAD] ;
   int result[MAX_THREAD];
   int i = 0;
   
    for(i = 0; i < MAX_THREAD; i++)
    {
        pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, myThread, &result[i]);
    }
    for(i = 0; i < MAX_THREAD; i++)
    {
        pthread_join(tid[i], &status[i]);
    }
    
    for(i = 0; i < MAX_THREAD; i++)
    {
        if (status[i] != 0) {
            printf("Thread:[%d] TID[%02x] result %d\n",i, (unsigned)(tid[i]), result[i]);
        } else {
            printf("thread failed\n");
        }
    }

   return 0;
}
```

I shouldn't be running out of threads:

```
cat /proc/sys/kernel/threads-max
7470
```

ulimit's seem to be "good":

```
[machine~]$ ulimit -s
10240
[machine~]$ ulimit -v
unlimited
```

Any idea why my pthread_join crashes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I shouldn't be running out of threads:

Note that this is a system-wide limit, so you could be running out of threads IF you have some other processes with many threads running.

On my `x86_64` system your program runs fine with with 1000 threads.

It *does* fail when built in 32-bit mode. That is because the default `ulimit -s` is 8MiB, and each thread inherits that setting. 8MiB * 307 == 2456MiB, which is above 2GiB.

If you are in fact on a 32-bit system, 2GiB might be the memory limit for user-space processes (this depends on how your kernel was configured).

Note that the failure is signaled by error return from `pthread_create`, and your program *does not handle* such error return correctly, which is why it crashes.

Specifically:

```
pthread_t tid[MAX_THREAD];  // uninitialized array of tid's
   
for(i = 0; i < MAX_THREAD; i++)
{
    // If this call fails ...
    pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, myThread, &result[i]);
    // ... then tid[i] is left as "random garbage" ...
}
for(i = 0; i < MAX_THREAD; i++)
{
    // ... which is used here, resulting in the crash.
    pthread_join(tid[i], &status[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Touche'.

> getconf LONG_BIT
> 32

So you've pointed out 1 error in the code, and 1 error in my assumptions, both of which are correct!
A: Code error is not checking the return value of pthread_create().
B: I assumed I was on a 64-bit machine with plenty of memory.

So I updated the program to check the return value of pthread_create(), and limit the create/join loops to the last "good" create.

```
#define MAX_THREAD 1000
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int something_worked(void) {
    /* thread operation might fail, so here's a silly example */
    void *p = malloc(10);
    free(p);
    return p ? 1 : 0;
}

void *myThread(void *result)
{
   if (something_worked()) {
       *((int*)result) = 42;
       pthread_exit(result);
   } else {
       pthread_exit(0);
   }
}

int main()
{
   pthread_t tid[MAX_THREAD] = { };
   void *status[MAX_THREAD] = { };
   int result[MAX_THREAD] = { };
   int i = 0;
   int ptc_rtn = 0;
   int max_t = MAX_THREAD;
   
    for(i = 0; i < MAX_THREAD; i++)
    {
        ptc_rtn = pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, myThread, &result[i]);
        if( ptc_rtn != 0)
        {
            max_t = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    for(i = 0; i < max_t; i++)
    {
        pthread_join(tid[i], &status[i]);
    }
    
    for(i = 0; i < max_t; i++)
    {
        if (status[i] != 0) {
            printf("Thread:[%d] TID[%02x] result %d\n",i, (unsigned)(tid[i]), result[i]);
        } else {
            printf("thread failed\n");
        }
    }

   return 0;
}
```

The program now does not segfault, and consistently returns between 302 and 304 pthread_creates, depending on what memory is currently available.

Thanks for finding my error, and the explanation of why it happens where it does!

Comment: If the answer resolved your problem, please accept it. It is not necessary to type the corrected program as a separate answer. Also, you could create a lot more threads even on a 32-bit machine -- you just need to explicitly ask for smaller stacks. In your case, 16K stack should let you create at least `300*8*1024/16 -- 153600` threads (though you are likely to run into some other limit first).

Comment: Sorry.  I've been a long time watcher, but new to asking.  Cheers!